# Meteor-Angular: Meteor.User is not assignable to type User

Tags: angular, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-useraccounts

i have an Angular Meteor project running. Its running but for some reason after i tryed to update all packages ( which was not working ) im getting the following errors while compiling.

```
client/imports/app/team/team-edit.component.ts (104, 33): Type 'Meteor.User[]' is not assignable to type 'User[]'. 
client/imports/app/team/team-edit.component.ts (161, 13): Type 'Meteor.User' is not assignable to type 'User'.
```

My User Interface looks like this:

```
export interface User extends Meteor.User {
  _id?: string;
  profile?: {
    name: string;
  }
}
```

And my Collection:

```
export const Users = MongoObservable.fromExisting(Meteor.users);
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe("users");
}
```

Usage in my Components:

`users: Observable<User[]>;`

`this.users = Users.find({});`

That error never showed up, but now it does and i dont know why and what changed.
Hopefully someone knows how to fix this :)

Meteor Version: 1.9.3

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.15",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.134",
    "angular-date-value-accessor": "0.0.2",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.9",
    "fontawesome": "^4.7.2",
    "har-validator": "^5.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.3.3",
    "meteor-rxjs": "^0.4.14",
    "ngx-ckeditor": "^0.3.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "rpg-awesome": "^0.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.3",
    "@types/meteor": "^1.4.28",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.44",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.14",
    "@types/sinon": "^4.3.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.16",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "sinon": "^4.5.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.2"
  }
```

Comment: Can you please add some info on your Meteor version and angular / typescript packages and the version from which you tried to upgrade to which versions?

Comment: @Jankapunkt added my package.json and Meteor Version

Comment: @Jankapunkt tryed to update to Angular 10 and newest Meteor version